# Can't select suggestion from jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, select, autocomplete, anchor

I am working with jQuery's autocomplete to create a autosuggest drop down for a "search members" input. The function lists the suggestions with the members avatar. Standard stuff. The following function works fine EXCEPT, it won't let me select one of the items.

```
 $(function(){
    $( "#main_search" ).autocomplete({
    source:'../ajax/search.php', 
    minLength:3
    })
        .data( "ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
             var pic_path = '<img src="../avatars/' + item.id + '/' + item.id + '_thumbnail.jpeg" onerror="this.src=\'../avatars/generic/generic_thumbnail.png\'" id="imgId" width="30px" padding="2px";>';

         return $( "<li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a><table><tr><td>" + pic_path + "</td><td style='color:#000000; font-size:0.7em; padding-left:10px;'>" + item.name + "</td></tr></table></a>")
        .appendTo( ul );

      };
```

My initial function...

```
  $(function() {  
     $('#main_search').autocomplete({
     source:'../ajax/search.php', 
     minLength:1
      });
  });
```

Worked fine in every respect - the selected suggestion could be clicked and it appeared in the input box. I initially thought it had something to do with my anchor tags and searching SOF showed that others have had a similar problem but in their case, the lack of anchor tags was the issue. I added the anchor tags but no success.

I am new to jQuery so apologies if this is simple.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED...

```
   $(function(){
     $( "#main_search" ).autocomplete({
     source:'../ajax/search.php',

     select: function(event, ui) {
     $( "#main_search" ).val(ui.item.name);
     return false;
     },

     minLength:1

     })
        .data( "ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
             var pic_path = '<img src="../avatars/' + item.id + '/' + item.id + '_thumbnail.jpeg" onerror="this.src=\'../avatars/generic/generic_thumbnail.png\'" id="imgId" width="30px" padding="2px";>';
                return $( "<li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a><table><tr><td>" + pic_path + "</td><td style='color:#000000; font-size:0.7em; padding-left:10px;'>" + item.name + "</td></tr></table></a>")
                .appendTo( ul );



      };
   });
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the issue was?